# How to construct additive inverse in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

A (locally small) abelian category has a canonical addition structure on its hom sets. In fact, this structure forms an abelian group.

Let $A$ be an abelian category. Here, an abelian category is a category with a $0$ object, binary products and coproducts, and kernels and cokernels, such that all epis are conormal and all monos are normal.

I have constructed the sum of morphisms $f, g : A \rightarrow B$ in the natural way. I have also found what the zero object should be. But I cannot manage to construct the additive inverse of a morphism. Can someone help me on this matter?

Comment: I'm a bit confused; if you are already in an abelian category (it looks like you assumed that), then that means you've guaranteed the existence of an inverse to your morphism. If you're not, then your inverse morphism doesn't necessarily exist. In other words, if all you have is $f: A \to B$, a zero object, and some bilinear operation $\cdot$ on $\text{Hom}(A, B)$, you cannot generally cook up a morphism $f': A \to B$ such that $f + f' = 0$ because this criteria alone cannot establish that $\text{Hom}(A, B)$ is an abelian group.

Comment: Have you looked at Freyd's *Abelian Categories*.

Comment: I edited to include the definition of abelian category that I am using.

Comment: How exactly have you defined addition on $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$? Is it through either $A\to A\oplus A\to B$ or $A\to B\oplus B\to B$ via the diagonal or summation morphisms?

Comment: I showed that both are the same.

Comment: So are you comfortable accepting matrix multiplication in an abelian category? Since then I think it works out essentially like linear algebra.

Comment: As Angina Seng mentioned, a great resource for developing the basics of abelian categories from axioms like these is Freyd's little book _Abelian Categories_.  The existence of additive inverses is Theorem 2.39, by the same argument as in BW.'s answer (I believe that book is in fact the original source for that argument).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f\colon A\to B$. You get a map $M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & f \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ on $A\oplus B$. Let $(a,b)\colon K\to A\oplus B$ be the kernel. Thus the composite $(a,af+b)\colon K\to A\oplus B$ is the zero morphism, so $a=0$, and consequently $b=0$. Thus $M$ has zero kernel, so is a monomorphism.

Dually, let $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}\colon A\oplus B\to C$ be the cokernel of $M$. Hence the composite $\begin{pmatrix} a+fb \\ b\end{pmatrix}$ is the zero morphism, so $b=0$, and consequently $a=0$. So $M$ is an epimorphism, and hence an isomorphism since we are in an abelian category.

Let $M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ be the inverse with components some appropriate morphisms. Then one finds
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a+fc & b+fd \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that $c=0$, hence $a=1$, $d=1$, and $b+f=0$, so $f$ has an inverse under $+$.